# How to compare row values for the next N-row window when a threshold is triggered in R

Tags: r

A shorten version of my df looks like the following:

```
rowNum <- seq(1:25)
A <- c(6,5,4,8,6,6,6,9,6,6,3,6,3,6,3,8,12,18,6,13,6,6,3,6,6)

df<- data.frame(rowNum,A, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df

rowNum A
   1   6
   2   5
   3   4
   4   8
   5   6
   6   6
   7   6
   8   9
   9   6
  10   6
  11   3
  12   6
  13   3
  14   6
  15   3
  16   8
  17  12
  18  18
  19   6
  20  13
  21   6
  22   6
  23   3
  24   6
  25   6
```

and I'm looking for an output 'B' to look like this:

```
rowNum A  B
   1   6  0
   2   5  0
   3   4  0
   4   8  8
   5   6  0
   6   6  0
   7   6  0
   8   9  9
   9   6  0
  10   6  0
  11   3  0
  12   6  0
  13   3  0
  14   6  0
  15   3  0
  16   8  0
  17  12  12
  18  11  0
  19   6  0
  20  13  13
  21   6  0
  22   6  0
  23   3  0
  24   6  0
  25   6  0
```

logic for the output B:

1. Find the max A over 4 consecutive rows after the threshold A >= 8 is  exceeded. 8 is the triggering point.
2. Once a row is used for comparison, it cannot be used again for another comparison. Comparison windows cannot overlap.
3. B returns the max A-value within the 4-consecutive row window and 0 otherwise.

Explanation:

In this example, first A >= 8 triggers at row 4, so the algorithm would

start comparing A-values from row 4 to 7. A is max at row 4 so B returns 8 at row 4.

Similarly for row 8~11.

The next threshold is triggered at row 16, so comparing A-value for row 16~19. Since A at row 17 is max, B returns 12 at row 17 and others return 0.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the solution over overlapping 4-observation windows, you could simply use `rollapply` from `zoo`:

```
library(zoo)
consecutive_rows <- 4
threshold <- 8

df$B <- rollapply(df$A, consecutive_rows, function(x) 
  ifelse(x[1] >= threshold, max(x), 0), partial=TRUE)
```

However, since you want a non-overlapping window after a trigger, things are more complicated. Here's a possibility that's not elegant but does the trick.

```
# Find the "naive" triggers
df$trigger <- df$A >= threshold

# Eliminate the triggers within a fixed window of the initial trigger
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if(any(df$trigger[max(1, i-consecutive_rows+1):(i-1)]))
    df$trigger[i] <- FALSE
}

# Start with B values at 0
df$B <- 0

# Compute the values across the trigger windows
for(i in which(df$trigger)) {
  range_comp <- i:min(i+consecutive_rows-1, nrow(df))
  df$B[range_comp] <- df$A[range_comp] * (df$A[range_comp] == max(df$A[range_comp]))
  }
}

# Cleanup
df$trigger <- NULL
```

Comment: rollapply's rolling windows seem to overlap, is there anyway to go around it? For instance, when the logic triggers at row 16, I will then compare row 16,17,18,19. After that, I'd be looking for triggering point starting from row 20 rather than row 17. thx

Comment: Ha, I see. Do you want the windows to be always non-overlapping, or only after a "trigger"?

Comment: I'd like the window to be non-overlaping 'only' after it triggers. thx

Comment: @ohmyan My new answer should work. Would you mind editing your question to make that clearer? I think your point 2 is what's ambiguous.

Comment: brilliant solution you have here! thx  
I tweaked your code a bit from "for(i in 1:nrow(df))" to "for(i in 2:nrow(df))" to accommodate the case when value of A at row 1 is >= the triggering point of 8.